# Find query giving no results & also warning Model "X" is not associated with model "Y" [APP/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php, line 342]

Tags: php, cakephp, model

Hi We are trying to migrate our Cakephp 1.3 code to Cakephp 2.x in this we are getting warning related to model associations and I am not getting to solve this.

When I am using my old query to fetch data with associated model(related Db table)

```
        $this->loadModel('User');
    $this->loadModel('FeaturedMentor');
    $featureData = $this->FeaturedMentor->find('all', array('order' => 'FeaturedMentor.id desc', 'limit' => 5));

    $this->User->Behaviors->attach('Containable');
    foreach ($featureData as $key => $featuredMentor){
        $featuredMentorArray[$featuredMentor['FeaturedMentor']['user_id']] = $this->User->find('first',
            array(
                'contain'=>array(
                    'UserReference'=>array(
                        'fields'=>array('zipcode','first_name','last_name','area_of_expertise')
                    ),
                    'UserImage',
                                      'Testimonial'         
                ),
                'conditions'=>array('role_id'=>Configure::read('App.Role.Mentor'),'User.id'=>$featuredMentor['FeaturedMentor']['user_id'],'status'=>Configure::read('App.Status.active'))       
            )

        );



    }
```

Than we are getting some warnings

```
Warning (512): Model "User" is not associated with model "UserReference" [APP/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php, line 342]
Warning (512): Model "User" is not associated with model "UserImage" [APP/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php, line 342]
Warning (512): Model "User" is not associated with model "Testimonial" [APP/Model/Behavior/ContainableBehavior.php, line 342]
```

And array of resultant data is coming blank like this

```
Array
(
[965] => Array
    (
    )

[851] => Array
    (
    )

[769] => Array
    (
    )

[734] => Array
    (
    )

[657] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

Our User model class code:

```
class User extends AppModel {

var $name = 'User';

var $actsAs = array(
    'Multivalidatable'
);
var $hasOne = array(
    'UserReference' => array(
        'className' => 'UserReference',
        'foriegnKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => true
    )
  );
var $hasMany = array(
    'UserImage' => array(
        'className' => 'UserImage',
        'foriegnKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => true
    ),
   'Testimonial' => array(
        'className' => 'Testimonial',
        'foriegnKey' => 'user_id',
        'dependent' => true
    )
);....
```

Our UserReference model:

```
class UserReference extends AppModel {

var $name = 'UserReference';

var $actsAs = array('Multivalidatable');
var $belongsTo = array('User');
var $validationSets = array(
    'admin' => array(
        'first_name' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'First name is required.'
            )
        ),
        'last_name' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => 'notEmpty',
                'message' => 'Last name is required.'
            )
        ),....
```

Our testimonial model class:

```
class Testimonial extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Testimonial';

var $actsAs = array('Multivalidatable');
var $belongsTo = array('User');

}
```

My question might be silly but I am trying to solve it but not getting solution so need help. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue actually my global variable(Configure::read('App.Role.Mentor')) in find query was not getting any values by which query giving no result.

Thanks...